# XMlHttpRequest is not working in Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

The following code is working fine in Google Chrome but not in Firefox. I can't make a request and can't receive a response.  I don't know what the problem is?

This is my Javascript code.

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }

  else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  // alert(str);
  xmlhttp.open("GET","server url/folder/file.php?q="+"string",true,"user","password");
  alert();
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
   {
 alert("response");
  alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
   var string=xmlhttp.responseText; 
    }
   }
   xmlhttp.send();
```

This is my server script which would respond.

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
$q=$_GET["q"];
echo $q;

?>
```

Comment: Are you using the SDK or are you building a XUL add-on? Where do you attempt to make the call from? SDK module like main.js? SDK content script? XUL overlay? Javascript code module? etc?

Comment: thanks for helping problem is resolved ..

Comment: thanks for your concern ,previous problem is resolved. I have another problem document.body.insertBefore(btn, document.body.firstChild); is not working in mozilla extension in overlay.js. I want to place it on the other youtube element.

Comment: I am working on firefox extesnion and my code is in overlay.js file

Comment: Then ask another question ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about if you add `X-Requested-With` header like this:

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
```

Also i would use `xmlhttp.send(null);` because some old Firefox browsers requires that `null` argument. And one last thing: I wouldn't call `xmlhttp.open` before I have first declared `onreadystatechange` listener.

Good luck, I hope this helps.

Comment: i have another problem document.body.insertBefore(btn, document.body.firstChild); is not working in mozilla extension in overlay.js. I want to place it on the other youtube element.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting the content type before calling the send?

like this

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Comment: That's only when using `POST` method. OP is using `GET` method.

Comment: i have another problem document.body.insertBefore(btn, document.body.firstChild); is not working in mozilla extension in overlay.js. I want to place it on the other youtube element.